# Trying to create a stored procedure (from text file) in java using MySQL connector

Tags: java, mysql, text-files, mysql-connector

As title says I'm trying to read and create a stored procedure from a simple text file... everything works fine in MySQL but as soon as I run the same SQL though the connector i get a syntax error.

```
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("st1.txt"));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = br.readLine();

    while (line != null) {
        sb.append(line);
        sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
        line = br.readLine();
    }
    String storedproc1 = sb.toString();
    System.out.println(storedproc1);
    PreparedStatement ps2 = conn.prepareStatement(storedproc1);
    ps2.execute();
```

Which gives this output:

[image: console output]

I'll reiterate that the SQL works fine in MySQL workbench .

Comment: what about trying to execute this SQL code in MySql to make sure it's right ?

Comment: When you say it works in mySql Workbench, did you open the exact same file from within workbench and execute it, or paste the text in?

Comment: I have executed the code in MySQL workbench and it creates the procedure as expected. It's the exact same code through connector isn't working.

Comment: I copied and pasted the SQL from MySQL to my program. My CREATE TABLE statements all worked fine... It just seems to throw an error over the stored procedure and nothing else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was wonderfully simple! Apparently the jdbc doesn't like the

```
Delimiter $$
```

line, I simply got rid of that line and the $$ after the

```
end
```

All is well! :)